# rails + rspec : Staying DRY when testing validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, dry, validation

Ok say I have the following model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :code
end
```

I'm doing the rspec unit tests for those validations. They look like this:

```
  it "should be invalid without a name" do
    country = Country.new(@valid_attributes.except(:name))
    country.should_not be_valid
    country.errors.on(:name).should == "can't be blank"
    country.name = @valid_attributes[:name]
    country.should be_valid
  end

  it "should be invalid without a code" do
    country = Country.new(@valid_attributes.except(:code))
    country.should_not be_valid
    country.errors.on(:code).should == "can't be blank"
    country.code = @valid_attributes[:code]
    country.should be_valid
  end
```

This doesn't look quite DRY. Is there any gem or plugin that automates this kind of stuff? 
I'd like to get something along these lines:

```
  it "should be invalid without a name" do
    test_presence_validation :name
  end

  it "should be invalid without a code" do
    test_presence_validation :code
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are remarkable for that : http://github.com/carlosbrando/remarkable

After you can do

```
it { should validate_presence_of :name }
```

Comment: what if I have a custom validate method? e.g. 
class User
  validate :check_my_stuff
end

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **factory_girl**, you can do:

```
  it "should be invalid without a name" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:country, name: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
```

One suggestion... don't use the keyword "should" on every spec.
Instead, write: "is invalid without a name"

Comment: +1 for the "should" recommendation. Since I wrote this, I have migrated to "should-less" specs.

Comment: @Cyle because descriptions should be written in present tense.

Comment: @Zenph But what if something break in the future, your description is rendered invalid? I think it makes more sense to specify the desired outcome.

Comment: @Cyle well, it's convention in the testing community :) Why rebel against a favoured practise? Check the sourcecode for your favourite companies' gems. There is a reason this way of describing is now common practise.

Comment: Further (not referring to you Cyle), this particular spec gives a false positive. Just because a model is invalid without a name, doesn't mean the lack of a name is causing invalidation. Much better to check `errors_on(:name)`, or simply `validates_presence_of` in accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try also [accept_values_for](https://github.com/bogdan/accept_values_for) gem.
It allows to do something like this:

```
describe User do

  subject { User.new(@valid_attributes)}

  it { should accept_values_for(:email, "john@example.com", "lambda@gusiev.com") }
  it { should_not accept_values_for(:email, "invalid", nil, "a@b", "john@.com") }
end
```